# GNU Make: how to join list and separate it with separator?

Tags: string, join, makefile, concatenation, separator

I have this:

```
FOO = foo1 foo2 ... fooN
```

and want to get join all these string and separate it with, for instance, colong:

```
foo1:foo2:foo3:...:fooN
```

How to do this in GNU Make, without using external UNIX tools?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571658/gnu-make-convert-spaces-to-colons

Answer (score 28):

See the code below.

```
# A literal space.
space :=
space +=

# Joins elements of the list in arg 2 with the given separator.
#   1. Element separator.
#   2. The list.
join-with = $(subst $(space),$1,$(strip $2))
```

Usage:

```
FOO = foo1 foo2 ... fooN

COLON_SEPARATED_FOO := $(call join-with,:,$(FOO))
```

Answer (score 21):

You can simply replace spaces with colon:

```
EMPTY :=
SPACE := $(EMPTY) $(EMPTY)
FOO = foo1 foo2 ... fooN
FOO_LIST = $(subst $(SPACE),:,$(FOO))
```

`FOO_LIST` is `foo1:foo2:...:fooN`.